# keyError when trying to get value from dictionary, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I can iterate and write to file with no problems in the second loop. But in the third loop when I try to call a value I get

```
R.write(str(dictList[s])+'\n')
KeyError: '<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent72>'
```

Here is the code:

```
f = open('advisor', 'rw')
e = open('dictionary.txt', 'rw')
R = open ('encodedAdvisor.txt', 'w')

import re

dictList={'key':'val'}
for line1 in e:
    kv=line1.split(',')
    key=str(kv[1])  
    val=str(kv[0])
    dictList.update({key:val})
for k, v in dictList.iteritems():
    R.write(str(k)+':'+v+':'+'\n') 
for line2 in f:
    spo = re.findall(r'(<.*?>)', line2)
    s = str(spo[0].strip())
    o = str(spo[1].strip())
    R.write(str(dictList[s])+'\n')
```

advisor file  :

```
advisor(<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent71>,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/AssociateProfessor7>)
advisor(<http://www.Department5.University9.edu/GraduateStudent97>,<http://www.Department5.University9.edu/AssociateProfessor0>)
advisor(<http://www.Department3.University9.edu/GraduateStudent60>,<http://www.Department3.University9.edu/FullProfessor6>)
advisor(<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent70>,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/AssistantProfessor2>)
advisor(<http://www.Department9.University9.edu/UndergraduateStudent260>,<http://www.Department9.University9.edu/FullProfessor9>)
advisor(<http://www.Department3.University9.edu/GraduateStudent59>,<http://www.Department3.University9.edu/AssociateProfessor5>)
```

dictionary file  :

```
GraduateStudent21158,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent66>
GraduateStudent21159,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent67>
GraduateStudent21160,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent68>
GraduateStudent21161,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent69>
GraduateStudent21162,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent7>
GraduateStudent21163,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent70>
GraduateStudent21164,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent71>
GraduateStudent21165,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent72>
GraduateStudent21166,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent73>
GraduateStudent21167,<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent74>
```

Comment: Did you even try to find out what value `s` is?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have trailing spaces for each line in your dictionary file.  I notice them when I select the text.  If this is in your actual file, this will raise an error since the strings will not match during the key lookup.  Try this:

```
for line1 in e:
    line1 = line1.strip()
    ...
```

Otherwise, test that your expected keys are actually in `dictList` keys:

```
expected = "<http://www.Department17.University9.edu/GraduateStudent72>"
assert expected in dictList
```

If an exception is raised you can track down the differences with `difflib`.  Any printed `+` or `-` will indicate the differences.  This should help you troubleshoot what's going on.

```
import difflib

actual = [k for k in dictList if "72" in k][0]
for i in difflib.ndiff(expected, actual):
    print(i, end="")
```

Comment: you're right about trailing spaces
key=str(kv[1].strip())
val=str(kv[0].strip())
solvedthe issue